# Multi-dimensional array with nested loop not displaying correctly

Tags: java, jtable, nested-loops

I have a multidimentional array that is for a JTable. But it is not displaying the data correctly in the JTable its displaying like this from up to down on each row  :

```
nidRbc  nidRbc  nidRbc  nidRbc  nidRbc  nidRbc  nidRbc  nidRbc  nidRbc
INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER
RBC identity    RBC identity    RBC identity    RBC identity    RBC identity    RBC identity    RBC identity    RBC identity    RBC identity
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
0:16382 0:16382 0:16382 0:16382 0:16382 0:16382 0:16382 0:16382 0:16382
maxRouteLength  maxRouteLength  maxRouteLength  maxRouteLength  maxRouteLength  maxRouteLength  maxRouteLength  maxRouteLength  maxRouteLength
NUMBER:3    NUMBER:3    NUMBER:3    NUMBER:3    NUMBER:3    NUMBER:3    NUMBER:3    NUMBER:3    NUMBER:3
Maximum length (km) of a locked route   Maximum length (km) of a locked route   Maximum length (km) of a locked route   Maximum length (km) of a locked route   Maximum length (km) of a locked route   Maximum length (km) of a locked route   Maximum length (km) of a locked route   Maximum length (km) of a locked route   Maximum length (km) of a locked route
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50
###.### ###.### ###.### ###.### ###.### ###.### ###.### ###.### ###.###
minRouteLength  minRouteLength  minRouteLength  minRouteLength  minRouteLength  minRouteLength  minRouteLength  minRouteLength  minRouteLength
INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER
Minimum length (m) of a locked route    Minimum length (m) of a locked route    Minimum length (m) of a locked route    Minimum length (m) of a locked route    Minimum length (m) of a locked route    Minimum length (m) of a locked route    Minimum length (m) of a locked route    Minimum length (m) of a locked route    Minimum length (m) of a locked route
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300 300
0:1000  0:1000  0:1000  0:1000  0:1000  0:1000  0:1000  0:1000  0:1000
maxMALength maxMALength maxMALength maxMALength maxMALength maxMALength maxMALength maxMALength maxMALength
NUMBER:3    NUMBER:3    NUMBER:3    NUMBER:3    NUMBER:3    NUMBER:3    NUMBER:3    NUMBER:3    NUMBER:3
Max length (km) for a Movement Authority    Max length (km) for a Movement Authority    Max length (km) for a Movement Authority    Max length (km) for a Movement Authority    Max length (km) for a Movement Authority    Max length (km) for a Movement Authority    Max length (km) for a Movement Authority    Max length (km) for a Movement Authority    Max length (km) for a Movement Authority
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50  50
###.### ###.### ###.### ###.### ###.### ###.### ###.### ###.### ###.###
minMAExtension  minMAExtension  minMAExtension  minMAExtension  minMAExtension  minMAExtension  minMAExtension  minMAExtension  minMAExtension
INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER
Min length (m) to extend an existing MA Min length (m) to extend an existing MA Min length (m) to extend an existing MA Min length (m) to extend an existing MA Min length (m) to extend an existing MA Min length (m) to extend an existing MA Min length (m) to extend an existing MA Min length (m) to extend an existing MA Min length (m) to extend an existing MA
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
0:1000  0:1000  0:1000  0:1000  0:1000  0:1000  0:1000  0:1000  0:1000
minTrainSeparation  minTrainSeparation  minTrainSeparation  minTrainSeparation  minTrainSeparation  minTrainSeparation  minTrainSeparation  minTrainSeparation  minTrainSeparation
INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER
Min distance (m) between two trains Min distance (m) between two trains Min distance (m) between two trains Min distance (m) between two trains Min distance (m) between two trains Min distance (m) between two trains Min distance (m) between two trains Min distance (m) between two trains Min distance (m) between two trains
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
0:1000  0:1000  0:1000  0:1000  0:1000  0:1000  0:1000  0:1000  0:1000
siteOwner   siteOwner   siteOwner   siteOwner   siteOwner   siteOwner   siteOwner   siteOwner   siteOwner
STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING
Country and owner of line (for communication identities)    Country and owner of line (for communication identities)    Country and owner of line (for communication identities)    Country and owner of line (for communication identities)    Country and owner of line (for communication identities)    Country and owner of line (for communication identities)    Country and owner of line (for communication identities)    Country and owner of line (for communication identities)    Country and owner of line (for communication identities)
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
[^/]{1,5}/[^/]{1,5} [^/]{1,5}/[^/]{1,5} [^/]{1,5}/[^/]{1,5} [^/]{1,5}/[^/]{1,5} [^/]{1,5}/[^/]{1,5} [^/]{1,5}/[^/]{1,5} [^/]{1,5}/[^/]{1,5} [^/]{1,5}/[^/]{1,5} [^/]{1,5}/[^/]{1,5}
siteName    siteName    siteName    siteName    siteName    siteName    siteName    siteName    siteName
STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING
Name of line (for communication identities) Name of line (for communication identities) Name of line (for communication identities) Name of line (for communication identities) Name of line (for communication identities) Name of line (for communication identities) Name of line (for communication identities) Name of line (for communication identities) Name of line (for communication identities)
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8   8
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
[^/]{1,15}  [^/]{1,15}  [^/]{1,15}  [^/]{1,15}  [^/]{1,15}  [^/]{1,15}  [^/]{1,15}  [^/]{1,15}  [^/]{1,15}
docNoSiteDataReport docNoSiteDataReport docNoSiteDataReport docNoSiteDataReport docNoSiteDataReport docNoSiteDataReport docNoSiteDataReport docNoSiteDataReport docNoSiteDataReport
STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING
Document number for site data report    Document number for site data report    Document number for site data report    Document number for site data report    Document number for site data report    Document number for site data report    Document number for site data report    Document number for site data report    Document number for site data report
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
docNoBaliseList docNoBaliseList docNoBaliseList docNoBaliseList docNoBaliseList docNoBaliseList docNoBaliseList docNoBaliseList docNoBaliseList
STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING
Document number for balise list Document number for balise list Document number for balise list Document number for balise list Document number for balise list Document number for balise list Document number for balise list Document number for balise list Document number for balise list
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
docNoGeographicalReport docNoGeographicalReport docNoGeographicalReport docNoGeographicalReport docNoGeographicalReport docNoGeographicalReport docNoGeographicalReport docNoGeographicalReport docNoGeographicalReport
STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING  STRING
Document number for geographical report Document number for geographical report Document number for geographical report Document number for geographical report Document number for geographical report Document number for geographical report Document number for geographical report Document number for geographical report Document number for geographical report
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11  11
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
nidC    nidC    nidC    nidC    nidC    nidC    nidC    nidC    nidC
INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER INTEGER
Country identity    Country identity    Country identity    Country identity    Country identity    Country identity    Country identity    Country identity    Country identity
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
1:1023  1:1023  1:1023  1:1023  1:1023  1:1023  1:1023  1:1023  1:1023
```

But I want it to display from left to right each data not from up to down

so should be like this :

```
nidRbc INTEGER RBC 1 1 1 0 NULL 0:16382
maxRouteLength NUMBER:3 Maximum 1 1 2 0 50 ###.###
minRouteLength INTEGER . ... .   etc etc..
```

This is my code right now :

```
// Create a list of node and compile the xpath expression
            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(
                    xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

            System.out.println("nodelist length : " + nodeList.getLength());
            System.out.println("constant length : "
                    + constants.getParamColumns().length);

            // Create a new string for the array
            arr = new String[nodeList.getLength()][constants.getParamColumns().length];

            // Loop through the list and save the data in a string array.
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < constants.getParamColumns().length; j++) {

                    System.out.println("content : "
                            + nodeList.item(i).getTextContent());
                    arr[i][j] = nodeList.item(i).getTextContent();
                    // System.out.println("Param : " + Arrays.toString(arr));

                }
            }
```

Comment: @kai almost working it displays correctly but the same data all the time it never displays this row : maxRouteLength NUMBER:3 Maximum 1 1 2 0 50 ###.###

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution :

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength()
                    / constants.getParamColumns().length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < constants.getParamColumns().length; j++) {

                    arr[i][j] = nodeList.item(
                            j + (i * constants.getParamColumns().length))
                            .getTextContent();

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reverse the index order, just reverse the index order:

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument,XPathConstants.NODESET);

System.out.printf("Nodelist Length:%1$d%nConstant Length:%2$d%n",
                  nodeList.getLength(), constants.getParamColumns().length);

arr = new String[constants.getParamColumns().length][nodeList.getLength()];
for(int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < constants.getParamColumns().length; j++)
        System.out.printf("Content:%1$s%n", arr[j][i]=nodeList.item(i).getAttributes().item(j));
```

Array indexing is left-to-right associative, meaning that the leftmost index is resolved first. Therefore, in a multidimentional array, one writes `array[rowNumber][columnNumber]`.

Comment: this doesnt work sir. It just getting the first items and display it correctly but on the second row it should get the second item but it gets the first againn. And on the third row its getting teh first again. So it solves the thirst problem but not everything.

Comment: @Sembrano should be fixed now

Comment: @Sembrano try using `.toString()`. Every object under the sun has a `.toString()` method.

Comment: @Sembrano why don't you try looking at the documentation, getting to understand the code, and actually trying to solve the problem?